# C++ <iostream> cin don't work properly

Tags: c++, input, cin, cout

```
World::World() {
    int width = -1;
    int height = -1;

    cout << "Aby rozpoczac gre wpisz rozmiar planszy" << endl;
    cout << "Aby uruchomic domyslne romiary zostaw pole puste" << endl;

    cout << "Podaj szerokosc: ";
    // I don't see what i'm  typing and i need to press enter twice;
    cin >> width;

    cout << "Podaj wysokosc: ";
    // I don't see what i'm typing too and make my program crash
    cin >> height;

    World(height, width);
}
```

couts work great but cin is soooo buged.
While first cin I don't see what I'm typing and I need to press enter twice;
While secend cin I don't see anything too and while I press any key, program crash

Comment: The code you're showing us should work.  Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: What do you think `World(height, width);` does?

Comment: My advice is to learn to use a debugger. And don't rush to think you found a some type of compiler or system bug.

Comment: Do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
 World(height, width);
```

constructs a temporary object and discards it. The member variable of the current object never get initialized properly.

Simplify your code. Move the code to get input data to the function that calls it. For example, use it in `main`.

```
int width = -1;
int height = -1;

cout << "Aby rozpoczac gre wpisz rozmiar planszy" << endl;
cout << "Aby uruchomic domyslne romiary zostaw pole puste" << endl;

cout << "Podaj szerokosc: ";
// I don't see what i'm  typing and i need to press enter twice;
cin >> width;

cout << "Podaj wysokosc: ";
// I don't see what i'm typing too and make my program crash
cin >> height;

World w(height, width);
```

Simplify the default construtor (replace `heightMember` and `widthMember` with the real member variables):

```
World::World() : heightMember(0), widthMember(0) {}
```